# Stack overflow during evaluation in OCaml

Tags: recursion, ocaml, stack-overflow

I encountered a stack overflow issue when implementing a square root approximation algorithm by Heron of Alexandria, given as follows:

> We start with an initial (poor) approximate answer that the square root is 1.0 and then continue improving the guess until we're within delta of the real answer.  The improvement is achieved by averaging the current guess with x/guess.  The answer is accurate to within delta = 0.0001.

My attempt at an implementation was as follows:

```
let squareRoot (x : float) : float =
  let rec aux input guess =
    if abs_float(guess**2. -. input) < 0.0001 then guess
    else aux input (guess +. input/.guess)/.2. in
  aux x 1.;;
```

However, this raises a `# Stack overflow during evaluation (looping recursion?).` error in the OCaml REPL. I tried implementing an identical algorithm in Python as follows:

```
def squareRoot(x):
  def aux (s, guess):
    if abs(pow(guess,2) - s) < 0.0001:
      return guess
    else:
      return aux (s, (guess + s/guess)/2)
  return aux (x, 1)
```

...which ran just fine. So I played around with the OCaml code, and changed my original attempt to:

```
let squareRoot (x : float) : float =
  let improve i g = (g +. i/.g)/.2. in
  let rec aux input guess =
    if abs_float(guess ** 2. -. input) < 0.0001 then guess
    else aux input (improve input guess) in
  aux x 1.;;
```

All I changed was wrapping the improvement portion of the algorithm in a separate function, but now the code runs successfully, without any stack overflow error!

I'd appreciate if someone could explain why this is so, and the mechanism behind the OCaml REPL/compiler possibly not recognizing a terminating condition in the recursive call in the my first iteration of code, etc.

Comment: You could add some debugging `Printf.eprintf` or use the Ocaml debugger

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Thanks for your suggestion! I've only been playing around with OCaml for a few days, sorry if this was too trivial a question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> aux input (guess +. input/.guess)/.2.
> ```

<sup>(the application of `aux` happens *before* the division by `2.` ...)</sup>

is parsed as

```
  (aux input (guess +. input/.guess))/.2
```

---

You really want

```
  aux input ((guess +. input/.guess)/.2.)
```

or even (read about [A-normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A-normal_form)s)

```
  let newguess = (guess +. input/.guess)/.2. 
  in
      aux input newguess
```

<sup>(which could be more readable, some people use names like `guess'`)</sup>

BTW, some people would code

```
  let guess =  aux input ((guess +. input/.guess)/.2.)
  in aux input guess
```

<sup>(there is no recursion, but [lexical scoping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Lexical_scoping))</sup>

but I don't like coding like that (reusing the *same* name `guess`)

As a rule of thumb, don't be shy in using parenthesis (or `begin` ... `end` which is the same) and intermediate `let` bindings. Both makes your code more readable.